# How do I execute the if statement 3 times?

Tags: java

I have a program which will keep on listing numbers. i.e. 1,3,5,3,2,5,7,,8,3,10,14, etc. How would I edit this for loop/if statement to check every 3 numbers? Is this correct?

```
for(int i = 0; i<theMessage.length;i+3){ 
    if(...)
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: `i+3` does nothing - you probably mean `i+=3`. It's irrelevant as your code `returns ` from inside the loop, so the loop will only execute once.

Comment: @HoboSapiens actually it does something, it gives compile error( and I'm certainly sure you already now that :) )

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between `i+3` and `i+=3`?

The first one says "take the value of `i` and add `3` to it

The second one says "take the value of `i` and add `3` to it, AND assign the result to `i`".

If you don't assign the result back to `i`, the value of `i` doesn't change ... and you repeat your loop over and over again with `i` set to zero,

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the value of **i** after every iteration so you have to use `i+=3` instead of `i+3` as `i+=3` is a shorthand for `i=i+3`

This would iterate through your numbers, every three number:

```
for(int i = 0; i<theMessage.length;i+=3){ 
    if(...)
    return ...;
}
```

and if you want to start from `1` you could start your loop from `1` instead of zero:

```
for(int i = 1; i<theMessage.length;i+=3){ 
    if(...)
    return ...;
}
```

This would iterate through your numbers, every three number:

```
for(int i = 0; i<theMessage.length;i+=3){ 
    if(...)
    return ...;
}
```

**Edit**(to answer comment *I wanted the loop to check every number in sets of three*)**:**

you could have a if statement like this:

```
if(theMessage[i] have condition)
    if(i+1<theMessage.length && theMessage[i+1] have condition)
        if(i+2<theMessage.length && theMessage[i+2] have condition)
            return what you want;
```

Comment: What is the difference between i +3 and i+=3?

Comment: i+3 will give you compile error : **error: not a statement**

Comment: This checks every third number, but if I wanted the loop to check every number in sets of three, how would that be done?

Comment: @user3358638 did you check my edit? Is it what you want?